# deploy wpf app with sql database

Tags: c#, wpf, setup-deployment

I am using Visual Studio Setup and Deployment deploying my wpf app. My aim is to package my wpf app so that I can install and run it in any machines which don't have sql installed and machines don't have internet access. I am using sql server express 2008 r2 and VS2010. I did some research, migration might be the solution but I have no idea how to use it and I don't find helpful tutorials for that. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition with a private deployment. See [this good article](http://erikej.blogspot.ru/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your setup Project, Go to project properties, Click for prerequisite button and check sql server version you are using for your project, also check the .Net version of the project.

if the host computer don't have the internet than select "specify the install option" as `Download the prerequisites form the same location as my application`.

This will create a full package of your application and ready to be deployed in any machine.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I followed your solution and it packaged sql server 2008 and .Net in the Debug file. But when I deploy in other machines without db and internet, it does not work. Regarding my wpf app, my DB has a "User" table which is used to manage my login users. I have to login and then upload my app. Is it because of the user login? do i need to install sql express (the packed folder sql espress 2008 is .exe file) in the testing machine? thanks again

Comment: for that you have to create your table in code dynamically, [follow this Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541050/creating-new-sql-server-table-with-c-sharp) may be it can help you